# insert password to binary field in mysql and check when log in to system

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, mysql-workbench

I'm developing a software and I have a  frame to save the users .
I have password field to get the password from  save new user frame. I chose binary data type to save password.after I saved a record and I look it from workbench and password field   has the "BLOB"  . I tried login frmae. but it did not work.I didn't use any encryption method.

my query is bellow  and the code.I also like to know what is the best way to save password.

```
    //get password from  password field in save user frame
    String password = txtUserPassword.getPassword().toString();

    /////////////////////////////////QUERY TO SAVE NEW USER////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //query to save the new user
     "INSERT INTO user(username,fname,lname,password,contact,type,isDeleted) VALUES( '"+userName+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+password+"','"+contact+"','"+type+"','false' )"


    ///////////////////LOG IN FORM CODE/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //in Login form ,get the user name and password and check with database value
     String username = txtUsername.getText();
            String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());

    //take the values to result set
            ResultSet rst = DB_Access.getData("SELECT username,password FROM user   WHERE BINARY  username='"+username+"' AND BINARY   password =  '"+password+"'  ");




            // check user existing or not in the if condition

             if(rst.next())

            {
                 Guesrname = txtUsername.getText(); // this user name to pass the user name to next form
                this.dispose();
                Seller sellFrame = new Seller(Guesrname ); // next appearing form
                sellFrame.setVisible(true);
            }

            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid user name or password");

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one problem.  This line is incorrect:

```
String password = txtUserPassword.getPassword().toString(); // returns something like"[C@12345"
```

Later on you do it correctly using the String constructor instead of `toString`:

```
String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
```

JPassword.getPassword() returns a `char []` not a string.  And oddly enough, the toString method of a char array does not return a string containing the text of the character array.

Modify the code where you enter the password to work like the code where your login with the password.  This should get you closer.

Comment: thanks you for the answer . I wanted to know best way to store password .I think I got got an answer but I don't know is correct or not.I'm going to encrypt password in my program and save it to mysql database .I use varchar(255) field to save the encrypted password . tell me if I am correct.